# InvalidCastException on database answer C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, exception

I'm trying to fetch data from a MySQL DB using C#, but I'm getting an `InvalidCastException` when I use the method `Int32.Parse()`.
This is my code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;database=my_db;uid=root;password=");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

try
{
    conn.Open();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM sale;";
    MySqlCommand qrycmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = qrycmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        String nome = (String) reader["nome"];
        int id = Int32.Parse((String) reader["id"]);
    }
}
catch (MySqlException e)
{
}
finally
{ 
    if (conn!=null)
        conn.Close();
}
```

But if I cast `reader["id"]` (which is `Object`) to `String` I can't see why it doesn't work...

Comment: What is the value of `reader["id"]`?

Comment: @Pietro No, it's an `int` *type*. What is its *value*?

Comment: I've two rows in the database, the first contains 3 in `id` field and the other is 4.

Answer (score 1):

if you need only two values dont use *. A.so dont cast but use `ToString()` instead:

```
 string query = "SELECT mome,ID FROM sale;";
    MySqlCommand qrycmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = qrycmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string nome = reader["nome"].ToString();
        int id = Int32.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
    }
```

Last it is even better to use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now it works, but may you explain me the difference between casting and using `ToString()`, please? Or anyway why `ToString()' works and casting not...

Comment: @Pietro you did not show your table definition. I guess your `id` column already _is_ some kind of integer (thatswhy `(string)reader["id"]` fails). So there is no need to first convert it to a string ( `ToSring()`) and then parse it again (`Int32.Parse`)...simply `int id = (int)reader["id"]` should work.